# evaluation of an integral involving algebraic numbers

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Define $A\colon[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ by 
 $A(x) =\begin{cases}   1,  &\text{if }x \text{ is algebraic}\\
0, &\text{otherwise}         \end{cases}$

Evaluate : $\int_{0}^{1}A(x)dx$

Is it riemann Integrable in the first place??
Intuitively it looks like $0$ which is also the answer. But I can't justify.

Comment: If a problem just wrote your first two lines, I would assume Lebesgue integral was meant.

Answer (score 2):

Notice every upper Rienmann sum equals 1, since every interval $[a,b],\ 0\leq a \leq b \leq 1$ contains infinitely many algebraic numbers; by the same argument, every lower sum equals 0.

This is due to the fact both the algebraic and transcendent numbers form dense sets in $[0,1]$. Another way to proceed from this fact is to notice it implies that the function is continuous nowhere (every point is a limit of a sequence of algebraic/transcendent numbers) and, therefore, by Lebesgue's criterion, is not Rienmann integrable.

It is Lebesgue integrable, though, with integral $1*0+0*1=0$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** check Lebsgue criteria for Riemann integrability.

**Added:**

**Lebesgue Criteria:**

> A function $f$ is Riemann integrable over $[a,b]$ iff
>
> i) it is bounded,
>
> ii) it has discontinuity on a set of measure zero.

Comment: Or just check upper and lower Riemann sums.